# Wordpress - ACF $array->ID not bringing anything?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced custom fields, and I have a "relationship field" inside a repeater in which the admin can choose a user.

This code succesfully brings the array but I don't undesrtand why `$idinverx = $inverx->ID;` won't work.

I know this might be pretty basic, but I've done this a lot of times before, I have no idea why it isn't working can someone help me out? this is my code:

```
wp_reset_query();

$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'inversion',
);

$the_query2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );

if ( have_posts() ) : 

    while ( $the_query2->have_posts() ) : $the_query2->the_post(); 

        if( have_rows('comisiones') ):

            while ( have_rows('comisiones') ) : the_row();
            {
                $inverx = get_sub_field('inversionista_que_recibe_comision_de_esta_inversion');
                print_r($inverx); // I get an array displayed here
                $idinverx = $inverx->ID;
                echo $idinverx; // Nothing gets displayed... why? :(
            }

?> 

<?php
            endwhile;

        else:
        // no rows found

        endif;

?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <p>No hay Inversiones</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This is what `$inverx` has inside:

```
Array ( 
    [ID] => 3 
    [user_firstname] => roberto 
    [user_lastname] => lozano 
    [nickname] => roberto 
    [user_nicename] => roberto 
    [display_name] => roberto lozano 
    [user_email] => roberto123@hotmail.com 
    [user_url] => http://roberto.com 
    [user_registered] => 2014-06-23 18:17:56 
    [user_description] => 
    [user_avatar] =>  
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$idinverx` is an array, so you shouldn't treat it like an object.
instead of using:

```
$idinverx = $inverx->ID
```

you should use:

```
$idinverx = $inverx['ID'];
```

Comment: I am glad you can move forward now =)